# Meaning of different manifold structures

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, curves

I would like to prove that if
$$ M = \{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: y^2 - 4x^2(1-x^2) = 0\} $$
and 
$$ P:(0,2\pi)\to M, \quad \theta \mapsto (\sin \theta,\sin 2\theta), $$
$$ Q:(-\pi,\pi)\to M, \quad \theta \mapsto (\sin \theta,\sin 2\theta), $$
are both bijective (this is easy) but $P^{-1}$ and $Q^{-1}$ do not give $M$ the same differentiable structure. What does this mean?

Also, I think that both structures are dipheomorphic, since $M\to M$ given by $P\circ \beta \circ Q^{-1}$, where $\beta(t) = t+\pi$ is differentiable. Is this right?

Edit: $P^{-1}\circ Q$ is $\theta\in(0,2\pi)\mapsto \pi-\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$ and is well defined.

Comment: It means they don't agree about which functions are differentiable.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Could you be more explicit? Are there incompatible charts?

Comment: The invariant content of a smooth structure on $X$, independent of a choice of charts used to describe it, is a subsheaf of the sheaf of continuous functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$ telling you which continuous functions are smooth. Two smooth structures are *different* (as opposed to *nonisomorphic*) if they give rise to different subsheaves; that is, if there is a continuous function $U \to \mathbb{R}$, $U$ an open subset of $X$, that one smooth structure thinks is smooth, while another smooth structure doesn't.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I am learning basic concepts on differentiable manifolds, and I would appreciate a lot if what is meaning in this context that both structures are different

Answer (score 1):

A differentiable structure on a manifold is, by definition, a maximal $C^{\infty}$-atlas, i.e. a collection of charts (such as $P$ and $Q$ on your example) being maximal with respect to the condition that they are $C^{\infty}$-compatible. This means that their change of coordinates are $C^{\infty}$.

If you have two possibly non-maximal atlases on a manifold you can ask if the charts of one of them are $C^{\infty}$-compatible with respect to the charts of the other one. If all of them turn out to be compatible, then the union of both atlases is a new atlas on the manifold.

However, if you find a chart in one of them which is not compatible with on of the charts of the other atlas, there is no way of finding a bigger atlas that contain both of them. Therefore this gives the idea that, although both atlases serve to give a certain set a differentiable structures, these are not compatible.

In your example, the changes of coordinates are $P^{-1}\circ Q:(-\pi,\pi)\to(0,2\pi)$ and $Q^{-1}\circ P:(0,2\pi)\to(-\pi,\pi)$. These compositions are bijective since $P$ and $Q$ are biyective, However e.g. they are not continuous, for example at $\pi/2$.

Comment: This means that taking an open involving $\pi$ on the differentiable structure of $M$ given by $P^{-1}$ should give me a chart that is not compatible with any chart of $M$ and its structure given by $Q^{-1}$, right?

Comment: Not necessarily non-compatible with all charts but maybe only one. In your case your atlases only have one chart each (since they are parametrizations of the equation defining $M$).

Comment: So I should better write what are $P^{-1}$ and $Q^{-1}$ and see that changes of coordinates are not well defined? That means that in $(0,2\pi)\cap (-\pi,\pi)$ the expressions of $P^{-1}\circ Q$ are not differential, so both charts are not compatible, right?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what has to be done.

Comment: Well, I meant that $P^{-1}\circ Q:(0,2\pi) \to (-\pi,\pi)$ is not differentiable. (Don't know why I wrote that intersection)

Comment: But, $P^{-1}\circ Q = \pi-\theta$ and is well defined!

Comment: You were right about taking the intersection, since, in order to compose the functions, you have to take a domain were they are both defined. Now,  $P^{-1}\circ Q=(\arcsin(\sin\theta), \arcsin((\sin2\theta)/2))$, however, note that, $\sin$ is being taken with domain $(0,\pi)$. $\sin$ is not injective in this interval, and therefore, $\arcsin$ is not well defined there.

Comment: But $P^{-1}:M\to (-\pi,\pi)$ and is a bijection, and $Q:(0,2\pi)\to M$ is also a bijection, so the composition is a bijection, it is well defined, or not?

Comment: Yes, they are bijections but they have different domains. For example, in order to do $P^{-1}\circ Q$, you would need that $Q(-\pi,\pi)\subseteq P^{-1}(0,2\pi)$. This is not true. You need to restrict to the set $P(0,2\pi)\cap Q(-\pi,pi)$.

Comment: I don't see the point, $P^{-1}\circ Q$ and $Q^{-1}\circ P$ have the intersection of the intervals as domain at the same time, but what gives this in order to prove that the manifold structures are different?

Comment: What are the incompatible charts, such that the change of coordinates is not dipheomorfism??

Comment: You are right, $P(0,2\pi)\cap Q(-\pi,\pi)=M$ (my mistake). However, the whole point is that when taking the inverse function of the sine, you need to be on a domain on which sine is invertible. In this case on both $(0,2\pi)$ and $(-\pi,\pi)$ you lose injectivity.

Comment: I don't think so, I just take the inverse of the map, which results into a piecewise function with $\arcsin$es, but it is also a bijection. And $P^{-1}\circ Q: \theta\mapsto \pi-\theta$

Comment: I think my mistake is saying that the functions are not defined, you are right that the y are well defined since as you said before they are biyective. However you lose continuity at for example $\pi/2$ since you "jump" from one branch where $\arcsin$ is defined to another. I'll edit the answer to reflect this,